# Why / When we get "older flags were not recorded helpful/declined"?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history

Today, I saw in my profile's Flagging history that notice:

> * older flags were not recorded helpful/declined

Could someone explain why/when that happen? is there some time limit for raised flags, I mean fater 10 days for example they will expire? or they are just not heplful?

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for disturbing, I already saw that question and found it not similar. But, the mistake I did, is that I didn't read it's answer (as I saw the question was different) which also reply to my question